# how create multiple objects using drf from a single payload

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

# in views under POST method

```
json_data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
display_name = json_data['displayName']
job_url = json_data['url']
start_time = json_data['timestamp']
execution_url = json_data['url']
execution_number = json_data['number']

    # #create stage execution
    # serializer = StageExecutionSerializer(request.data)
    # if serializer.is_valid():
    #     serializer.save()

    # #create platform
    # serializer = StageExecutionSerializer(request.data)
    # if serializer.is_valid():
    #     serializer.save()
```

I am struggling to figure out the most efficient way to take request.data and create objects leveraging DRF from this data.

Passing in display_name, job_url, etc. to the serializer doesn't make sense to me because those have already been deserialized by json.loads, however this is the route I might have to take.

The ideal scenario would be to pass in request.data to each serializer, and have it automagically know which key/values to take when creating object.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, if you pass dict to a serialiser then it will only take into account the fields that it has defined in it's meta class.

You'll notice that if you do something like:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    a = serializers.CharField(max_length=3)
    b = serializers.CharField(max_length=3)
    class Meta:
        fields = ('a', 'b')
s = MySerializer(data={'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3})
s.is_valid()

# This will print the original data dict
print(s.initial_data) 

# > {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

# This will render the data according to serializer and fields `to_representation` method, so no extra fields
print(s.data)  

# > {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}

# This will print the validated field data, so no extra fields
print(s.validated_data)  

# > OrderedDict([('a', '1'), ('b', '2')])
```

This example would also work with a ModelSerializer.

Comment: good to know, what about if the field is "display_name" but the value in the payload is displayName (as shown in OP), is there a way to workaround that?

Comment: Hmm, that is a bit more difficult.  You'd need to either modify the data dictionary keys before the serializers binds the data to a field (in the view or serializer.__init__), or implement your own field that takes a sort of `data_key` attribute for the fields whose name does not match the key in `data`.  I found an example of someone else doing something similar:
https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/967 and 
https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-rest-framework/commit/b2c54dc391ffcd36f2bcfc2efbf5966aad5504f8 show someone adding this functionality to rest framework.